# How do I alter this roman numeral converter code so that it correctly counts the numbers place?

Tags: c, linux

So I've got code that looks like this

```c
#include <stdio.h> 

void decimal_to_roman(int num)
{ 
    scanf("%d", &num);
 
    while(num != 0)
    {
 
        if (num >= 1000)       // 1000 - m
        {
           printf("C");
           num = num % 1000;
        }
        
 
        else if (num >= 500)   // 900 -  cm
         {
 
         if (num < 900)   // 500 - d
        {           
           printf("D");
           num = num % 500;
        }
         else
         {
            printf("CM");
            num = num % 100;
         }
         }
 
        else if (num >= 100)   // 400 -  cd
        {
           if (num < 400)
           {
           printf("C");
           num = num % 100;
           }
           else
           {
              printf("CD");
              num = num % 100;
           }
        }
 
        else if (num >= 50)   // 100 - c
        {
           if (num < 90)
           {
              printf("L");
           num = num % 50; 
           }
           else{
              printf("XC");
              num = num % 10;
           }
        }
 
        else if (num >= 10)   
        {

        if (num < 40)
        {
           printf("X");           
           num = num % 10;
        }
        else
        {
           printf("XL");
           num = num % 10;
        }
        }
 
        else if (num >= 5)
        {
        if (num < 9)
        {
           printf("V");
           num = num % 5;                   
        }
        else
        {
           printf("IX");
           num = 0;
        }
        }

        else if (num >= 1)
        {
           if (num < 4)
           {
              printf("I");
              num = 0;
           }
           else
           {
              printf("IV");
              num = 0;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't work properly, for obvious reasons, but I'm having trouble on slotting in both num/1000 and num % 1000 that I need to make it proper, since when I try putting both in it gives me errors. I'm pretty new to coding so I have no idea where to start. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should apply some proper indentation to make the code more readable. That is even more importnt for beginners.

Comment: What do you mean by "Count the number place"? What did you try and what errors did you get?

Comment: In your code you should not do any modulus calculation or assign any specific number. Just subract the value of the digit you have just printed.

Comment: I would also suggest not to used any nested `if` in this case. Just strictly go down from 1000 to 900, to 500, etc. until you get to 4 and finally 1.

Comment: You are using "C" for both 1000 and 100.

Comment: Hint: On SO, giving feedback to comments and answers is essential.